# pesistence.xml of other project

Tags: java, jpa

I have an API for my database model and JPA controllers and I add the jar of that `AProject` to my `BProject`. When I declare my API in `BProject`.

And the error is `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named "MyPersistenceUnitName" in my "BProject"`.

Is it possible or should I create what i'm calling in my `AProject`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reuse the code you had in AProject.jar. According to [persistence chapter of Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html):

> The JAR file or directory whose META-INF directory contains
>   persistence.xml is called the root of the persistence unit. The scope
>   of the persistence unit is determined by the persistence unit’s root.
>   Each persistence unit must be identified with a name that is unique to
>   the persistence unit’s scope.
>
> Persistent units can be packaged as part of a WAR or EJB JAR file or
>   can be packaged as a JAR file that can then be included in an WAR or
>   EAR file.
>
> If you package the persistent unit as a set of classes in an EJB JAR
>   file, persistence.xml should be put in the EJB JAR’s META-INF
>   directory.
>
> If you package the persistence unit as a set of classes in a WAR file,
>   persistence.xml should be located in the WAR file’s
>   WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory.
>
> If you package the persistence unit in a JAR file that will be
>   included in a WAR or EAR file, the JAR file should be located in
>   either
>
> The WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR
>
> The EAR file’s library directory